# Android load big txt vertices file

Tags: android, file, binary, readline, vertices

is there any way to load a big file to a buffer faster than txt files?
i ve read somewhere that it is much more faster to work with binaries files 
I m trying to load a file with vertices to a vbo.
I m doing this reading line by line , parsing the floats , then put them to an array list , then to a float array and then load to the buffer , but with big files it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Mmapping big file containing floats and accessing it via byte buffer could be fastest option
as it is fetched by paging and not by usual random access files.

Additional advantage is that it does not count against your heap and is not subject for garbage collection either. Disadvantage is that it is not very portable between different systems.